# Very confused about how to parse xml with namespace prefixes

Tags: asp.net, xml

So, I need to be able to parse xml files that could include namespace prefixes. I've tried doing this with a sample file and it gives me back null when trying to get a nodelist, even when I specify a node that has no attribute prefixes.

I've been trying to research this and it keeps coming back to the fact that without the namespace prefix defined, it won't work, so I've added code that I thought would do this, but it's still giving the same results.  Here's some code I've added:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xml.Load(Server.MapPath("~/SomeLesson/imsmanifest.xml"));
    populateBaseNodes();
}

private void populateBaseNodes()
{
    treeViewMenu.Nodes.Clear(); // Clear any existing items
    TreeNode treenode = new TreeNode();
    treenode.Text = "organizations";
    XmlNodeList baseNodeList;

    string xmlns = xml.DocumentElement.Attributes["xmlns"].Value;
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("adlcp", "http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("imscp", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("imsss", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

    baseNodeList = xml.SelectNodes("/manifest/organizations/organization/item", nsmgr);

    TextBox1.Text = baseNodeList.Count.ToString();

    foreach (XmlNode xmlnode in baseNodeList)
    {
        TreeNode treeNodeCatalog = new TreeNode();
        treeNodeCatalog.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["identifier"].Value;
        treeNodeCatalog.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
        treeViewMenu.Nodes.Add(treeNodeCatalog);
    }

    treeViewMenu.CollapseAll();
}
```

(marc_s) Here's the XML in question that needs to be parsed:

```
<manifest identifier="Navigating_in_QuickBooks_-_Introduction_MANIFEST" version="1.3"
  xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:imscp="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"
    xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3" 
    xmlns:imsss="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1 imscp_v1p1.xsd
                         http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss imsss_v1p0.xsd
                         http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3 adlcp_v1p3.xsd 
                         http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlseq_v1p3 adlseq_v1p3.xsd
                         http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlnav_v1p3 adlnav_v1p3.xsd">

  <metadata>  
     <!-- not relevant here ... -->
  </metadata>
  <organizations default="TOC1">
     <organization identifier="TOC1">
        <title>Navigating in QuickBooks - Introductory Lesson</title>
        <item identifier="I_SCO0" identifierref="SCO0"> 
            <title>Navigating in QuickBooks - Introductory Lesson</title>
        </item>
     </organization>
   </organizations>
   <resources>
     <!-- not relevant here ... -->
   </resources>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not showing us what your XML looks like - but two comments:

1. you don't need to add the `xsi` prefix, and I'm not sure what the `schemaLocation` prefix is supposed to do ....
2. when you've **defined** the schema prefixes, you also need to **use** those prefixes in your XPath, of course!

Again, not knowing what your XML structure looks like, I cannot really tell what you need - but something along the lines of:

```
 baseNodeList = xml.SelectNodes("/adlcp:manifest/adlcp:organizations/adlcp:organization/imscp:item", nsmgr);
```

or whatever other XML namespace prefixes your source XML requires.

**Update:** seeing your XML makes it clearer: see the root node - it has a **default** XML namespace (the one with `xmlns="...."` and no explicit prefix):

```
<manifest identifier="Navigating_in_QuickBooks_-_Introduction_MANIFEST" version="1.3"
     xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"  <=== DEFAULT namespace!!!
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:imscp="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"
     xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3" 
     xmlns:imsss="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss"
    ................>
```

That means: **ALL** your subsequent nodes that don't have a specific XML prefix **will be in that default namespace**.

Unfortunately, .NET XML parsing has problem with defining a default namespace without prefix - so my best solution is to create a namespace with a prefix for the default namespace, and then use it:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);

// add default namespace, with a prefix for .NET 
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1");

baseNodeList = 
   xml.SelectNodes("/ns:manifest/ns:organizations/ns:organization/ns:item", nsmgr);
```

Do you get any results now??

Comment: Sorry, here is the xml with some stuff genericized to protect the innocent ;-)

Comment: The problem is that in the xml, the only prefix used throughout the document is in a node that I'm not parsing and it only uses adcp.  There are no prefixes in the node I'm parsing, so it doesn't make sense that I would use it in the Xpath, does it??

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if this question were deleted and I could repost it along with the xml?

Comment: @LeviWallach: does the root node not have any XML namespaces prefixes on it?? Can't you just trim down your XML and post it here?? It would be quite helpful! We don't need **all the details** (all the nodes) - but the gist of it would be very helpful...

Comment: sure, I'll try:<manifest identifier="Introduction_MANIFEST" version="1.3"
  xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:imscp="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"
 xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3" 
 xmlns:imsss="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss"
 xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1 imscp_v1p1.xsd
                         http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss imsss_v1p0.xsd
                         http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3 adlcp_v1p3.xsd>

Comment: ...cont: <organizations default="TOC1">
  <organization identifier="TOC1">
   <title>Introductory Lesson</title>
   <item identifier="I_SCO0" identifierref="SCO0"> 
    <title>Introductory Lesson</title><!--defaults to Course Title-->
   </item>
  </organization>
 </organizations>

Comment: <resources>
  <resource identifier="SCO0" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormType="sco" href="player.html">
   <file href="player.html" />
   <dependency identifierref="ALLRESOURCES" />
  </resource>
  <resource identifier="ALLRESOURCES" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormType="asset">
   <file href='imsss_v1p0objective.xsd'/>
<file href='config.xml'/>
<file href='extend/custom.xsd'/>
<file href='extend/strict.xsd'/>
<file href='preview.htm'/>
[etc]
  </resource>
 </resources>
</manifest>

Comment: @Levi - please edit your question and add the details there, do not stuff it all into the comments.

Comment: @Jason, I'm sorry, I'm somewhat new to stack overflow and still learning how to post.  I didn't realize I could edit after I posted.  I'm trying to go back and inlcude the xml but am getting some errors which are preventing me from saving the edit.  I'll keep working on it...

Comment: Yes!  Thank you Marc, that finally did it!  I'm able to parse.  My only other issue is that I'm not sure that I'll be able to predict that this will be the same default namespace for every file - this page possibly will be a general tool. I suppose the very fact that I need to account for this default namespace means that I can't programmatically pull it, or I could but it would be using some different kind of parsing mechanism?

Comment: @LeviWallach: if you check out your `xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI` I believe this will always hold the default XML namespace (if present)

Comment: @marc_s - See my answer below. Were you unable to create a namespace manager entry using `String.Empty` for the namespace prefix?

Comment: @marc, yeah, I just tried your code below (and altering the selectnodes method to remove the prefix in the XPath and got back an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

In the XML you posted the default namespace controlling all of the elements in your sample file is:

```
xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"
```

This namespace does not define a prefix so you must add this namespace to your namespace manager using a blank prefix. I think you should be able to use this code to define the default namespace (using String.Empty to specify a blank prefix):

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace(String.Empty, "http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1");
```

Comment: You would *THINK* this approach would work - but in .NET XML parsing, **it doesn't**; if you try it with this XML file, even though everything *seems* to be set up properly, you get back an empty list of XML nodes.....